# How to use server IP as proxy

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, lan

I have full access to a server which is located in some other country. My IP address has been blocked blocked by a website and I need to use my server IP as proxy to access that particular website. I tried out with the server IP address in `LAN Setting->use Proxies` in my **Chrome Browser** but I am unable access the internet when i use that IP. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just entering the server address on client side isn't sufficient. You need to set up your server to behave as a proxy server using something like [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html) or other alternative.